# Aspdotnetstorefront Topic-Editor Document Manager File-Upload

Tags: file-upload, aspdotnetstorefront

(Sorry my English is not so good)

I have the following message in my Aspdotnetstorefront Topic-Editor, in the Document Manager, after that i choise the upload pdf-document and click on the upload-Button:

"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

It comes only by file-sizes about 30 MB, to 30 MB it gives no problems.

The following changes i have allready do:

In the web.config:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="65536"/>
```

And in the topics.aspx:

```
<tcontrol:RadEditor runat="server" RadControlsDir="rad" id="radDescription">

     <DocumentManager MaxUploadFileSize="41943040" UploadPaths="~/Images" ViewPaths="~/Images" DeletePaths="~/Images" />

</tcontrol:RadEditor>
```

Can anyone help me?

Great thanks vor a fast answer.